# How to get the keyid of an object in a JSON file if one of the fields contains a specific string

Tags: json, bash, select, filter, jq

I have the following JSON:

```
{
  "201110131738QP27N": {
    "parent": 17,
    "name": "CentralServer",
    "status": "Active",
    "count": 6
  },
  "201803271459ICV69": {
    "name": "subaccount1",
    "status": "Active",
    "count": 1
  },
  "2018032715008ZM2G": {
    "name": "subaccount2",
    "status": "Active",
    "count": 1
  },
  "201803281536PSKR4": {
    "name": "Este e um teste",
    "status": "Active"
  }
}
```

I would like to know if there is any way I can enter the contents of the key name and "jq" gives me the KeyID?
For example:
I inform "**subaccount1**" on the command and jq returns me: **201803271459ICV69**"

I'm trying the following command but with no success.

```
cat file.json | jq -r '. | select(.[].name | contains("subaccount2")) | keys '
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`jq`** solution:

```
jq -r 'to_entries[] | select(.value.name == "subaccount1").key' file.json
```

The output:

```
201803271459ICV69
```

Comment: Awesome! Worked perfectly
Thank you so much